# Fundamental of certificate based authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, security, ssl

I searched a lot and found many answer on how to implement certificate based authenticate in wcf. But my questions are related to fundamental of it.

While implementing Certificate based authentication on production, does client provides its certificate which server needs to add on its trusted people store? Or server provides a certificate (signed by server).

I guess while configuring wcf server, we just configure certificate location and store. We never bind it with any domain. So any client that present this certificate can access my service. And in case certificate needs to be bound to a domain. They why cannot we just allow all requests from that domain.

When client calls a wcf service, it present its certificate. Does this certificate only carry public key? And can this certificate by stolen (as it travels on network) and used by hacker to consume the web service.

I have idea about how ssl woks. In case of ssl, browser take care of all this stuff but in case of wcf service (when we want to allow only specific client to access our service) how it gets managed.

Thanks In advance.

**Let me make it simple :**

1. I want to create a web service and i want that three clients (A, B and C) can use it. I want to authenticate these three clients by certificate. While setting up, do these clients need to send their certificates to me. Or I have to create certificate for them? Will client share their private key as well (while setting up)
2. Do I need to put these certificates into trusted people store?
3. When they request for webservice, they will present their certificate (with public key only). If they present it with public key only, hackers can steal this public key and request for my web service. How will my webservice distinguish between hacker/actual client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While implementing Certificate based authentication on production, does client provides its certificate which server needs to add on its trusted people store? Or server provides a certificate (signed by server).

In a secure service, a server certificate is mandatory.  Client certificate is optional.  The server can be configured to *ignore*, *accept*, or *require* client certificates.

> I guess while configuring wcf server, we just configure certificate location and store. We never bind it with any domain. So any client that present this certificate can access my service. And in case certificate needs to be bound to a domain. They why cannot we just allow all requests from that domain.

Not sure how you'd bind to a domain without a client certificate.  You mean with reverse DNS lookup?  That requires an IP address, and a malicious user can spoof it.

The typical means of restricting access via client certificates it to map one of the fields in the client certificate (typically the subject or domain) to a user account.  You can have one-to-one mappings (each client certificate represents a single user) or many-to-one mappings (if the client has a certificate that is in a list, he is treated as a certain user).  If the certificate isn't mapped, the user is treated as anonymous.  More information [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication) assuming you are using IIS.

> When client calls a wcf service, it present its certificate. Does this certificate only carry public key? And can this certificate by stolen (as it travels on network) and used by hacker to consume the web service.

The certificate FILE that you handle during setup contains both the public and private key.  The certificate itself is contained in that file; it contains a payload that includes the public key and a MAC signature, but does not include the private key.

The private key is put into secure storage and is never sent in any HTTP request.  Only the certificate (and its public key) are sent over the wire.  The whole file is not sent.

### Edit to Respond to Further Questions

> I want to create a web service and i want that three clients (A, B and C) can use it. I want to authenticate these three clients by certificate. While setting up, do these clients need to send their certificates to me. Or I have to create certificate for them?

During set up, a client certificate must be generated by a certificate authority (CA).  You can actually serve the role as an intermediate CA (for production certificates) who derives his authority from a root CA (such as Verisign).  In order to do that you must request a certificate from the root authority.  They will issue you a certificate with its own public key, and give you a private key, so that you will have the ability to generate and digitally sign certificates of your own.  You typically have to pay for this privilege.

In addition, you can become your own root CA!  This is common during the development phase.  Basically you generate your own public and private keys and start generating your own certificates.  These are called [self-signed certificates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  The down side of being your own CA is that nobody will recognize your public key, so in order for anybody to use your certificates they would you have manually add you to their list of trusted root authorities.

> Will client share their private key as well (while setting up)

No, nobody ever shares a private key with anybody, throughout the entire PKI.  Ever.  This is exactly why it is referred to as a private key.  The only exception is when you are a certificate authority and you are generating a private key in order to create a certificate.  In this case the private key must be carefully guarded during handling.  It is never, ever sent over the wire as part of SSL communications.

> Do I need to put these certificates into trusted people store?

Yes and no.  If you are using a self-signed certificate, yes.  If you are using a certificate that was signed by an CA that in turn has a certificate that was signed by a root CA, the root CA must also be in the list of trusted root authorities, but you probably don't have to add it.  It should be there automatically.  That is the whole purpose of using trusted root authorities-- everybody is supposed to know about them and should recognize their public keys.  Root certificates are typically distributed to browsers automatically during installation and kept up to date using the browser's patch and update services.

> When they request for webservice, they will present their certificate (with public key only). If they present it with public key only, hackers can steal this public key and request for my web service. How will my webservice distinguish between hacker/actual client.

This is a great question.

It's important to recognize that an SSL handshake includes a lot more than sharing certificates.  There is also, among other things, a challenge/response step.  Here's how it works:

Your server will generate a random number or time stamp ("challenge") and send it to your browser, challenging it to encrypt it.  The browser will then encrypt the challenge using the private key (which it only has access to).  This "response" is then sent back to the server for verification.  The server uses the public key from the client certificate to decrypt the response.  Since only the client has the private key, and since the public key is publicly known and verifiable (because it is contained in a signed and tamperproof certificate), the server can tell that the response had to have been encrypted by the client associated with the certificate.  And because the challenge was generated by the server, and is different every time, a hacker cannot impersonate the client by replaying the response from a previous challenge.

Comment: nice explanation. I have edited my question. It would be great if you can put some light on that as well.

Comment: Thank you very much John! But You missed a very important point. I want to allow only A, B and C to access my web service (not anybody else). Since many other people would have valid certificate signed by CA. Where would i define only A,B and C's certificates should be allowed.

Comment: Please see the portion of my answer that begins "The typical means of restricting access via client certificates it to map one of the fields in the client certificate (typically the subject or domain) to a user account."  Link provided for specific configuration instructions.  Hope this helps.

Comment: What challenge-response step? The client provides a digital signature over his certificate and the handshake messages so far, signed by his private key, in the CertificateVerify message. See RFC 2646 and successors. Where in that document is there a challenge-response message? A. Nowhere.

Comment: I think you mean RFC 2246. The challenge is the conversation itself, and the response is the signature. The point for OP to understand is that the input to the signature contains entropy that is not fully chosen by the client. But you're right, there is a lot more detail we could go into.

Answer (score 2):

> While implementing Certificate based authentication on production, does client provides its certificate which server needs to add on its trusted people store?

Yes, if the server asks for it, otherwise no.

> Or server provides a certificate (signed by server).

Always. These aren't mutually exclusive. Both can happen.

> I guess while configuring wcf server, we just configure certificate location and store. We never bind it with any domain. So any client that present this certificate can access my service. And in case certificate needs to be bound to a domain. They why cannot we just allow all requests from that domain.

I can't make head or tail of any of that.

> When client calls a wcf service, it present its certificate.

If the server asks for it.

> Does this certificate only carry public key?

Yes.

> And can this certificate by stolen (as it travels on network) and used by hacker to consume the web service.

No, because it only contains the public key.

**EDIT** Re 'Let me make it simple':

> While setting up, do these clients need to send their certificates to me.

Only if they are self-signed.

> Or I have to create certificate for them?

That's another possibility, but then you would have to become a mini-CA (Certificate Authority). Too broad.

> Will client share their private key as well (while setting up)

Definitely not.

> Do I need to put these certificates into trusted people store?

There is no such thing as a 'trusted people store'. There is a trusted *certificate* store, which usually only contains CA certificates. You only need to add the actual client certificates if they are self-signed. You might need to add their CA certificate if it isn't already there.

> When they request for webservice, they will present their certificate (with public key only). If they present it with public key only, hackers can steal this public key and request for my web service.

I've already answered that. No.

> How will my webservice distinguish between hacker/actual client.

They won't 'just' present their certificate: they will also provide a digital signature over it signed by their private key. Possesion of the certificate alone is worthless to an attacker. Without the private key they cannot even get past the TLS handshake. Your web service won't even see them.

Comment: +1 Out of interest, why would the server not ask for the client certificate? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't ask by default. It needs to be told to do so. Mostly the server doesn't care who the clients are (e.g. a public website allowing anonymous access), or uses a different form of authentication, such as a login form with username/password, as almost universally used with HTTP. Most clients, i.e. browsers, don't even have client certificates.

Comment: EJP- I have updated the text to make the question more clear. Could you pls add some value to it.