# Client authentication - dealing with client-side ceritificates

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ssl, x509certificate

I have an ASP.net web application and my clients need to authenticate to my website with client-side v3 certificates.

All I need to check is that:
1- the certificate is valid
2- The "Issued To CN" has a specific value

I do the following in my MVC action:

```
var req = Request.ClientCertificate;
```

`req` has a property called `IsValid` which is enough for requirement (1). Now, the issue here is that I cannot check the CN because I believe it is stored in another property of the type `byte[0]` called `Certificate`.

I tried reading the certificate like this:

```
var x509 = new X509Certificate(req.Certificate);
```

But I get two exceptions:

```
'x509.Issuer' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException'
'x509.Subject' threw an exception of type     'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException'
```

How can I read the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is to map certificate attributes (e.g. the Subject or CN) to one or more users.  This is done via [IIS configuration](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication).

After that is completed, all MVC has to do is [check the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263486/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-mvc).

See also [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263959/fundamental-of-certificate-based-authentication).